# What is the proper python method of server-side verification for non-managed Google Play In-App products?

Tags: android, python, in-app-purchase, google-play, server-side-validation

I've searched everywhere for a clear example of how to verify In-app products on our server in Python.

We have a game with several In-app products and we're experiencing a large number of fraudulent receipts.

We would like to verify the authenticity on our Python server with Google to confirm that the receipt is valid before offering the In-app product to the player.

We have the json data returned by Google and we're already sending it to our server. We just aren't sure how to take this data and verify that it's legitimate.

We've searched through Stack Overflow and Google but all of the references we're finding don't appear to be relevant.

Can you point us in the right direction with some code examples?

Answer (score 0):

Google provides a [Purchase Status API](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/gp-purchase-status-api.html) which allows you to verify that the package name/product id/token is a valid purchase on the backend.

Comment: How does this answer the question?